# JUnit optional/required tests

Tags: junit, maven-3, testng, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin

I have Junit 4.8.2 and maven 3
Some tests in my application should fail the build in case of failure and some of them shouldn't (just report that the following optional tests failed)

How can I do it with junit and if I can't then maybe testng can?

E.g. I have two test cases:

First is not really important and can failed because of connection timeout, service unavailability and so on so on. So if it fail, I don't want to fail whole build, just to let user know about it and write to console

Second is really important one and if it fail - build should be failed as well

I know about @Ignore - it is not what I'm looking for, because I don't want to skip any tests.

I know about @Category so if you know how to configure surefire plugin to say: if category com.me.Required - build should be failed in case of failure and if category com.me.Optional - build should not be failed

Comment: What exactly is your question? Have you writting test cases which will fail or not? How do they look like? How does your pom look like ?

Comment: I have updated my question. Please take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using the [failsafe](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/) plugin for your tests that are allowed to fail and set the [testFailureIgnore](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/verify-mojo.html#testFailureIgnore) flag to true.

To [use](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html) the failsafe plugin you have to add the plugin to you pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The surefire plugin will per default execute test named like [*Test*](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes). The failsafe plugin will per default execute the test named like [*IT*](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes).

Given the tests

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class SurefireTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

and

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class FailsafeIT {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertTrue(false);
    }

}
```

Running `mvn install` will now result in

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
.
.
.
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running SurefireTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.062 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
.
.
.
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running FailsafeIT
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.072 sec <<< FA
ILURE!
...
Results :

Failed tests:   test(FailsafeIT)

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
.
.
.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.174s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Sep 29 08:19:38 CEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is it allow to apply testFailureIgnore to not all tests? I don't think so

Comment: @Sergey Kravchenya I don't think this option is available. So I suggest to run the test that should not fail with the surefire plugin and to run the test that are allowed to fail with the failsafe plugin (and testFailureIgnore set to `true`)

Comment: is it possible to have two these plugins together? If so, please edit your answer and I'll mark it as accepted :) Thanks

Comment: @SergeyKravchenya Of course it is possible to run two plugins together. I added a detailed example. You should read the plugin documentations (and maybe some [maven lifecycle documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)) carefully to understand what happens.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use @Ignore, see [Is there a way to skip only a single test in maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835705/is-there-a-way-to-skip-only-a-single-test-in-maven)
2. You can skip tests in a certain package [Is there a way to tell surefire to skip tests in a certain package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389744/is-there-a-way-to-tell-surefire-to-skip-tests-in-a-certain-package) or http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html or
3. You can use JUnit 4.8 Categories JUnit Categories http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/junit.html
4. You can use skipITs http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/verify-mojo.html#skipITs

I think JUnit 4.8 Categories is actually what are you looking for.