# Skip single test with maven with command line options

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I would like to skip a single test (e.g. `com.example.MyTest`) when building a project with Maven from the command line.

I'm aware of similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/835705/2032064), but they all require either modification of source code or `pom.xml`. I would like to do without modifications. **How can I exclude a test using command line options only?**

What I've tried so far after reading [some documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html) is

```
mvn clean install -Dtest="*,!com.example.MyTest"
```

but the test is still not skipped. I'm using surefire plugin version **2.19** and JUnit **4.11**.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turns out that (at least in Surefire 2.19), the test pattern doesn't work with fully qualified class names. So the right solution is

```
mvn clean install -Dtest="*,!MyTest"
```

i.e. without the package path.

In Surefire 2.19.1, it [should be possible](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html) to use fully qualified names. In versions older than 2.19, neither seems to work.

Comment: It didn't work for me :( This is how I'm using it: ` test -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j-dm.xml -Dtest="*,!Testname1Test,!Testname2Test,!Testname3Test,!Testname4Test" `.

Comment: What version of  surefire are you using?

Comment: Version: [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test)

Comment: I guess that your version of Surefire doesn't support excluding tests like this. Try upgrading to 2.19.

Comment: When I start Jenkins, it says the version is maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4. I already updated the pom version my app, but I don't know how to do that in Jenkins. I'm still searching how to do that.

Comment: I had to escape the "!" (use "\!" instead) otherwise I get a bash "event not found" error, see https://serverfault.com/questions/208265/what-is-bash-event-not-found