# How to exclude specific flies from mvn build path from command line?

Tags: java, maven

while executing **mvn clean install -DskipTests** I want to exclude a file com.java.test.Test.java from build path(as it has some error). How to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven - exclude folder from build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25262794/maven-exclude-folder-from-build)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<exclude>` tag in your pom.xml to exclude files in Maven. For more information see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

Another way is adding the class to an exclusion pattern as an argument like:

```
mvn clean install -Dtest="*,!Test"
```

For more information see
[Skip single test with maven with command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35288189/skip-single-test-with-maven-with-command-line-options)

Comment: I updated my answer, this might help you @AjaySinghMeena