# Travis CI build failing because my project is one level down from the git repository directory

Tags: maven, travis-ci

```
Git repository:- xyz/repository
Project:- xyz/repository/project/pom.xml

.travis.yml: [kept in /project]
language: java
script: mvn clean install
```

Travis CI always executes the script in xyz/repository
I tried with below

```
language: java
script: cd project 
        mvn clean install
```

But it still executes in xyz/repository

Error: The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory

Could someone please help?

Comment: I would recommend to change the structure of your git repo...apart from that you should use `mvn clean package` or `mvn clean verify` but not `mvn clean install`...

Comment: Hey! It worked. I was having the yml file in wrong format. I have removed the install goal and put the package goal as per your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @khmrbaise, what do you mean by changing the structure of the git repo? Do you mean add a pom.xml to the base level (xyz)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a bash script with simple cd commands before maven clean install.
Then reference your bash script in .travis

build.sh :

```
cd git_repo/
mvn clean install
```

.travis.yml :

```
script: ./build.sh
```

Comment: That's a clean idea. Will do this. Thanks!

Comment: Will ask a follow up question if you don't mind.
How can I exclude one particular test from CI build?

I tried with: `mvn clean install -Dtest=!*DaoTest`

But the above ended up excluding all the tests.

Comment: It's a question for another thread. You can use @Ignore with junit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835705/is-there-a-way-to-skip-only-a-single-test-in-maven

Comment: Did you get "./build.sh: Permission denied" by any chance? If so, what was your workaround?

Comment: Sounds like another issue, just see how to use chmod 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-do-i-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubu

Answer (score 5):

Got it working.

Corrected the yml format.

```
language: java
script: 
  - cd project 
  - mvn clean install
```

The above works.